# Need to sort/search by language in GMail

Tags: gmail, localization, gmail-search

Because someone w/ the same name has used wrong email address, I constantly get spam emails in non-English languages.

If I could sort/search them, I could bulk-delete/bulk-spam them to clear out my inbox.

I need a solution to this ...

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no built-in solution to search by language on Gmail. From [makeuseof.com](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-advanced-gmail-search-operators-you-should-know/#:%7E:text=Curiously%2C%20there%20used%20to%20be%20a%20search,find%20emails%20written%20in%20a%20specific%20language):

> There used to be a search operator called *language:* or *lang:* that would allow you to find emails written in a specific language. This one must have been discontinued, since it is no longer working for me.